# What is the time complexity of mmap in Linux?

Tags: linux, big-o, time-complexity

In big O notation I guess and with respect to the size of memory requested.  Also, can we assume that the memory is not committed lazily because that makes things complicated.

To be precise for the call `mmap(0, n, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)` where `n` is a variable.

Comment: "can we assume that the memory is not committed lazily because that makes things complicated" - well that also happens to be the part that makes it useful

Comment: You can't assume that because it's *wrong*. If you want to do that you can make up whatever conclusion you want.

Comment: Elaborating on @sehe's comment, `mmap` is fast precisely *because* it's lazy. Out of curiosity, is there any particular reason you want to know this? It might be easier to answer your question if we have a bit more surrounding context. If this is purely theoretical, the answer is probably "it depends on the implementation and internal structure of the kernel." If this is more practically motivated, then the motivation would help us give a better answer.

Comment: Don't know the answer to the first question. Guess you could look at the source to determine that. For the second question, I assume by "committed" you are referring to writes to a memory mapped file. If so, there is no guarantee that writes to a memory mapped file will be immediately synced back to the file. The mmap man page says: "The file may not actually  be updated until msync(2) or munmap() is called."

Answer (score 1):

In this [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html) state that,

*MAP_ANONYMOUS initialize the region to zeros.*

I believe this process is O(n) complexity, but possibly more efficient :

*On some systems using private anonymous mmaps is more efficient than using malloc for large blocks. This is not an issue with the GNU C Library, as the included malloc automatically uses mmap where appropriate.*